# Unable to handle error in $stateChange, using ui-router and AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, firebase-authentication

I am including authentication in my app, using Google's `Firebase`. I have been following their documentation https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html. Though this method uses `stateChange` and as I understand, this has been deprecated by `ui-router`. So looking online I turned my script from the example from this:

```
app.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", 
       function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
            console.log('HELLO')
            if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
                $state.go("login");
        }
    });
}]);
```

to:

```
app.run(($transitions, $state) => {
    $transitions.onError({}, ($transition$) => {
        if ($transition$.$to().name !== 'init' && $transition$.$from().name !== 'error') {
            $state.go("login");
        }
    });
});
```

I am trying to handle the error, so when a user tries to access a page that requires authentication, it directs them back to the login screen. The second approach is working, through it freezes when it tries to change the state to `login`.

**question**

Why is my script failing to re-direct the user to the `login` page when they try to access pages that require authentication?

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider, ) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        component: 'login'
    })
    .state('patents', {
        url: '/patents',
        component: 'patents',
        resolve: {
            currentAuth: function(authentication) {
                return authentication.requireAuth();
            }
     });
}]);


app.factory('authentication', ['$rootScope', '$location', '$firebaseAuth', '$firebaseObject', function($rootScope, $location, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject) {

var auth = $firebaseAuth();

//LOAD OF OTHER AUTHENTICATION METHODS

    return {

        requireAuth: function() {
            return auth.$requireSignIn();
        }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar use case.  I'm short on time to actually figure out the answer to your specific question, but I can provide a solution to your situation.

Let's handle authentication before the Transition starts.

```
app.run(["$state", '$transitions', '$q', 'Auth',
    function($state, $transitions, $q, Auth) {

  //overrides default error outputting by ui.router
  $state.defaultErrorHandler(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });

  //redirects to login page if we're not signed in
  $transitions.onBefore({to: 'home.**', from: '**'}, function(trans) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    Auth.$requireSignIn().then(function() {
      //we're signed in, so proceed to home.**
      deferred.resolve();
    }).catch(function() {
      //we're not signed in and home.** requires authentication
      //so resolve with the state you want to reroute to, refreshing
      //the url w/ reload === true
      var params = { reload: true };
      deferred.resolve($state.target('login', undefined, params));
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  });

  //redirects to home page if we're signed in
  $transitions.onBefore({to: 'login.**', from: '**'}, function(trans) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    Auth.$requireSignIn().then(function() {
      //we're signed in, so lets avoid going to login, and instead
      //go to our authenticated state
      var params = { reload: true };
      deferred.resolve($state.target('home', undefined, params));
    }).catch(function() {
      //we're not signed in, so continue to login.**
      deferred.resolve(); 
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  });
}]);
```

Config would look something like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('login', {
  url: '/login'
  // + some template/controller/resolve...
})
.state('home', {
  url: '/home'
  // + some template/controller/resolve...
})
```

And heres the auth factory

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
  return $firebaseAuth();
}]);
```

docs for onBefore can be found [here](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.ihookregistry.html#onbefore).

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer @Vincent. All working, though I have multiple pages with in the application that require authentication, so where you have put `$transitions.onBefore({to: 'patents.**', from: '**'}`, how do I have multiple states that return the user to the login page?

Comment: Ignore me. Read the documentation. Thank you for your help